# Adding/Removing Roles is not working (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

On some Discord servers my code to add/remove roles, however, on some it doesn't. I checked and they all have the correct permissions, so I'm kind of stumped.

Whenever I run the `>addrole` or `>removerole` command I always get the same Discord error message. It is *":x: Couldn't find mute role. Make sure you didn't make a typo (roles are case-sensitive too!)"*. I set this for when a user makes a typo while typing what role they want to add.

The format for the commands are as follows:

> addrole [@User] [RoleName]
>   removerole [@User] [RoleName]

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send(":x: Insufficient permission.").then(msg => msg.delete(4000));
  let rolemember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!rolemember) return message.channel.send(":x: Could not find user.").then(msg => msg.delete(4000));
  let role = args.join(" ").slice(22);

  if (!role) return mesage.reply(":x: Specify a role.");
  let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
  if (!gRole) return message.channel.send(":x: Couldn't find mute role. Make sure you didn't make a typo (roles are case-sensitive too!)");

  if (!rolemember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.channel.send(`:x: User does not have role "${gRole.name}".`).then(msg => msg.delete(4000));
  await (rolemember.removeRole(gRole.id));

  try {
    rolemember.send(`:white_check_mark: Your role "${gRole.name}" in`, message.guild.name, "has been removed :confused:.");
  } catch (e) {
    message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: ${rolemember} Your role "${gRole.name}" has been removed :confused:.`);
  }
  let removeroleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("Role Changes")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .addField("Role Removed", gRole)
    .addField("Removed From", rolemember)
    .addField("Removed By", message.author);

  let logChannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "logs-reports");
  if (!logChannel) return message.channel.send(":x: Couldn't find logs channel.").then(msg => msg.delete(4000));
  logChannel.send(removeroleEmbed);
}

exports.help = {
  name: "removerole"
}
```

I expect that the role should be added, however, it is not and the same error message is what I get every time.

Comment: Could you please share what the command looks like when typed in to discord. eg: "!removerole ..."

Comment: Done. The format is now shown near the beginning of the post.

Comment: What is the value of `args`? Try logging the value of `role` after `let role = args.join(" ").slice(22);`, see if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As `.find('name', 'name')` is DEPRECATED. That thing you use may not work.. Instead, use `let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === role)`. I am new to this community. So please fogive if I do something wrong.

Try replaceng the let gRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", role); with let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === role) This should work because it is how it is supposed to be, sorry I am not very good at explainin

**Note:**
`Collection.find()` is not totally deprecated, just format `Collection.find("name", "yourName")` is deprecated!

Comment: I don't think `Collection.find()` is deprecated? Could be wrong but see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find). `message.guild.roles.find(r => r[a] === role)` should be identical to `message.guild.roles.find(a, role)`

Comment: Wait, I don't understand how this gives me a way to reference the found role in the code. Could you please explain?

Comment: `Collection.find()` is not totally deprecated: the way where you use it with a property and a value (e.g.: `Collection.find("name", "yourNameHere")`) si deprecated. With that said, that wya to use it still works and so it can't be the source of any error in the code. The only thing that you'll notice is that it logs a DeprecationWarning in the console

Comment: Yes, `Collection.find()` is not totally deprecated. Only `Collection.find("name", "yourNameHere")` is. Try replaceng the  `let gRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", role);` with `let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === role)` This should work because it is how it is supposed to be, sorry I am not very good at explaining.

Comment: @freddyrobinson Yes, Collection.find() is not deprecated. If you read my answer correctly. Only the format `Collection.find("name", "yourName")` is depreceated.

Comment: @federicoGrandi Yes, it still works with some things, but as I have experienced, not with guild.roles.